# Cosa vuol dire "una psicologa del piffero"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> -- E si capisce, -- cominciò a dire, -- basta guardare i genitori come si occupano dei figli. O li lasciano allo sbando, senza una dritta, un'attenzione, o peggio ancora li massacrano di richieste, e fai questo e fai quello, e guai a uscire dai binari... Una babele, signora Cantirami, una vera babele! Non come vostro figlio. Filippo sí che sa cosa vuole! Determinato, deciso. Uno che se ne fa anche due baffi della famiglia, se decide...!
>   
>         Come sarebbe se ne fa due baffi della famiglia? Cosa mi vuol dire questa *psicologa del piffero*?

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piffero/) ho trovato che "piffero" può avere questo significato figurato:

> fam. In frasi colloquiali, con valore negativo, niente, nulla: *non capisci un piffero!*

Tuttavia, non so se questa definizione abbia senso nel contesto sopra citato: una psicologa "del nulla"? Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "psicologa del piffero" nel brano precedente?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Del piffero", riferito a cose e persone, ha proprio quell'accezione che hai trovato tu.

Una "psicologa del piffero" è una psicologa da poco, che non vale niente. Non conosco il testo, ma potrebbe addirittura significare che non è una vera psicologa, ma qualcuno che si atteggia.

L'espressione originale, ben più volgare, sarebbe "del cazzo". Per... analogia di forma, si sostituisce con "piffero" ed è accettabile in [articoli](http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2013/10/22/intellettuali-del-piffero-libro-sugli-showmen-del-pensiero-ad-ogni-costo/752244/) e testi di linguaggio colloquiale.

Comment: In questo caso si tratta di una vera psicologa.

Comment: Nell'articolo di cui hai messo il link si menziona il "pifferaio di Hamelin". Ha qualcosa a che vedere con questa espressione?

Comment: @Charo non proprio. Il paragone del pifferaio è per richiamare come gli intellettuali di adesso si fanno seguire dalla gente comune, in modo quasi acritico. Quindi sono intellettuali "del piffero", da poco, e "con il piffero", che incantano la folla con le loro parole come il pifferaio con la sua musica.

Comment: Trovo che il pifferaio di Hamelin e la mutua non c'entrino niente, ma per il resto condivido la spiegazione eufemistica data da @laureapresa.

Comment: Altre espressioni "eufemistiche" con lo stesso significato: _della domenica_, _della mutua_